# Getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'field_name__c' of undefined from VF Page

Tags: visualforce, spring17

I have a `visualforce page` embedded in the `standard page layout` of a custom object and it is throwing the below error for a sandbox which was refreshed from production a month before Spring 17 release went live (error screenshot is shown below). But I am not getting any error from a sandbox which was refreshed recently from production after the Spring 17 release went live.

I guess this issue is due to Spring 17 release. 
I would appreciate any find of help or suggestion.

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'RIMS_Service_Request_ID__c' of
>   undefined"

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandip, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. If you [edit] your post to include any relevant markup, I'm sure you will get better answers.

Comment: Did you have a look at the debug log? Looks like the object is not initialised for which you are referring the Service Request Id custom field.

Comment: Thanks Marty for your suggestion. I tried initializing the object before referring it but I am getting the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

I think, when the refresh happened all the data in sandbox also got deleted. So please check in the sandbox that all relevent records/data exists.

also you have not handled the null check on the query thats why the above error thrown.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Manu for the suggestion but the data is still there in the object.